# The concept of adjoint operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm reading about adjoint operators from Kolmogorov's book and it seems that an adjoint operator must be a linear operator. Is it true? If so, are there generalizations of the concept of adjoint opeator to nonlinear operators?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428922/adjoint-of-a-nonlinear-operator This may be interesting reading for you. The typical definition of an adjoint forces linearity, so whatever alternative definition exists will have to account for this.

Comment: This paper may be of interest: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~schwrtz/PhysicsPapers/43:JMathPhys_38_3841.pdf It's very physics-oriented however.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you!