# Does this operator have an adjoint?

Tags: analysis

Does this Operator have an adjoint?:

$F:C[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: x\mapsto \left(\int_0^1 x(s) ds\right)^2 $

I would say no, because:

- F ist not linear (can be proofed)
- if $f:H_1\rightarrow H_2$ is a linear and limited operator ($H_1$ and $H_2$ are hilbert-spaces)
- $C[0,1]$ is a pre-hilbert space (And part of square integratable functions $L^2$)

Therefore, if there would be an adjoint of F with domain $C[0,1]$, then there would also be one for F with domain $L^2$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question. Since $F$ is not linear it doesn't even make sense to talk about its adjoint.

Comment: regardless of C[0,1] not being a hilbert space?

Comment: How are you defining adjoint? If it is $\langle v, Au\rangle = \langle A^*v, u\rangle$ then $A$ has to be linear. You can see why from this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428922/adjoint-of-a-nonlinear-operator.

Comment: I see! Yes that's how it's defined in my books. Thank you! :)