# Approximate adjoint of a non-linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

First of all, I'm not a mathematician, I'm only but a geophysicist.

I'd like to know if there is a technique to find an analytical adjoint operator of a non-linear operator, such that:
$$\langle T(x), y \rangle \approx \langle \hat{T}^*(x), y \rangle$$
where $\hat{T}^*$ would be the approximate adjoint operator.

From what I could gather from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428922/adjoint-of-a-nonlinear-operator?newreg=85eda4eeb7f843cdbdef9a882a284166), $T$ has to be linear for the adjoint to be found by techniques such as integration by parts to find the weak form.

To ilustrate, if I have an operator $T = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, it is easy to deduce using integration by parts that $T^* = - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. However, how could I find the adjoint of $T = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^2$? Should I try to linearize it first?

I hope I can learn from you all, thanks in advance for the patience.

Comment: Your choice of $T$ is still linear, integration by parts will work.

Comment: Remember "linear" means "linear in the operand", not "linear in the differential operator", i.e. $T(af+bg) = a Tf + bTg$.  The square on the derivative is really composition, not multiplication, and the composition of two linear operators is again linear.

Comment: hm, interesting, thx for the answer! I tried to use integration by parts and it didn't work. Either way, is there a way to handle non-linear cases?

Comment: also, if any of you knows the adjoint of $\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right)^2$ please do let me know haha.

Comment: I wasn't able to prove that there is a $T*$ operator that respects $\int \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} y(t) \mathrm dt = \int x(t) T^*(y(t)) \mathrm dt$.
I wasn't able to solve it through integration by parts @NinadMunshi :/

Comment: It is its own adjoint....

Comment: hm, I don't understand why :/